# What does sudo apt-get install curl command do? Why does it require the password?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I tried installing PlayOnLinux by using the steps according to a YouTube video, [Install MS Office 2010 on Ubuntu 12.04-14.04](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFP0pvgTK6s), and used the command

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Then it requested my password which I entered.

Can anyone please explain what this command line does?

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to execute commands randomly found on the Internet without understanding what they're doing, especially when they start with `sudo`. Good answers below, but you should have asked before running it.

Comment: Note: instead of  `apt-get` you can just use `apt`.  It provides a simpler interface and nicer output. Or just use a visual package manager.

Answer (score 29):

First let's look at each part of the command individually:

1. `sudo` is short for "substitute user do" and executes commands as another user. Most commonly, it is used to temporarily become "root" (Linux equivalent of admin). Software installation would not work without `sudo` in the front. This is the part of the command that needs your password. For security reasons, you should always try to use `sudo` rather than straight-up [logging in as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root/488045).
2. `apt-get` is one program in the `apt` suite, which deals with software installation and management. Linux distributions typically feature a package manager that is used to install, configure, and remove software; Ubuntu uses `apt` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155538/what-is-apt-and-aptitude-in-ubuntu).
3. `install` tells `apt-get` to install a package on your computer. The command will search through your repositories (typically just the official Ubuntu repositories via the internet) for a package, download it, copy it to your computer, and configure it. For more specifics see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540937/what-does-apt-get-install-do-under-the-hood).
4. `curl` tells `apt-get` what package to install. Specifically, `curl` is a data transfer program, and is commonly used to download websites or files via the command line. More details available on its [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/curl.1.html).

So, putting everything together, you are going to download the package `curl` from the internet and install it by giving the `apt-get` program root privileges.

As Calimo noted in his comment, you should be careful executing random terminal commands you find on the internet. And you should be **VERY** careful executing any command that starts with `sudo`, since it has the potential to damage the really important parts of your system.

Comment: Actually sudo is short for 'substitute user do' - though it's frequently used to do something as root, that's not it's only use, you can also do things as any other user you have a password for.

Comment: @RichBradshaw The sudo man page mentions "superuser" once, and "substitute," not at all. http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

Comment: Thats interesting, I'd assumed it came from Su, which definitely is substitute: http://linux.die.net/man/1/su

Comment: Furthermore, "superuser" doesn't really make sense because "sudo" can run commands as any user, not just root.

Comment: Then there's the connection, I concede the point. Though when I was learning this stuff, I mostly wanted a helpful mnemonic for sudo, and superuser do worked quite nicely for that.

Comment: "_execute a command as the superuser or another user_" I think the main usage is to execute commands as a superuser, and thus it stands for _Super user do_ only. We don't tell `sudo` to substitute the user for `root`. But with additional options, we _can_ make it run commands on behalf of another user too.

Comment: Changed it to "substitute user do" since both [the project page](http://www.sudo.ws/) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) list it as such. You learn something new every day :)

Comment: Regarding "substitute user do" versus "super user do": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ASudo#Is_it_.22substitute_user_do.22_or_.22superuser_do.22.3F

Comment: @Ergwun that's a cool bit of history (also lol at wikipedia edit wars). I'm going to leave it as "substitute" since new users will never encounter a sudo that is only limited to the root account.

Comment: @TheSchwa Thanks for the wonderfully clear answer. So is there a way I could uninstall this curl app?

Comment: You can uninstall it with `sudo apt-get remove curl`. Also, if I answered your question completely, consider accepting my answer using the checkmark.

Answer (score 9):

`man curl`

> curl  is  a tool to transfer data from or to a server, using one of
>   the
>          supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS,  IMAP,
>          IMAPS,  LDAP,  LDAPS,  POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS,
>          TELNET and TFTP).  The command is designed to work without user  inter‐
>          action.

This is curl.

The command `sudo apt-get install curl` means you are going to download and install `curl` into your system.

So when you use `sudo` and every time you use `sudo` you will be asked for your password to ensure that you have permissions to do things for your system

Read [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/306766:linux-101-introduction-to-sudo) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) for more information about sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Running a `sudo someCommand` will not even check if that command exists/is valid/in the PATH. The moment the shell sees `sudo`, it will prompt for a password.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you use a command  starting with `sudo`, it means that you are using the computer as a root privileged. And every command that make change to a computer should start with `sudo` because Linux needs to make sure the administrator is making those changes. 
you can also prompt a `sudo su`command before any other commands. so that you do not need to enter your pass-phrase every time you want to change the computer settings.